# Add double quotes to variables in awk output

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

For each line in this file, I'm separating based on | and need to add double quotes
Here are the contents of file

```
ks|active|0.1|0
ks|dc|0.1|0
ks|process|0.1|0
```

Desired output

```
ALTER TABLE "ks"."active" WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;
ALTER TABLE "ks"."dc" WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;
ALTER TABLE "ks"."process" WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;
```

Here's the command I'm using (it's not appending values to $1 and $2

```
cat table_list | awk -F '|' {'print "ALTER TABLE " $1 "." $2 " WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;" '}
```

output from this command i'm using

```
ALTER TABLE ks.active WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;
ALTER TABLE ks.dc WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;
ALTER TABLE ks.process WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? `awk -F '|' {'print "ALTER TABLE \"" $1 "\".\"" $2 "\" WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;" '} table_list`

Comment: Is there a typo in the first line of your desired output?

Comment: Or `sed 's/\(.*\)|\(.*\)|.*|.*/ALTER TABLE "\1.\2" WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;/' table_list`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `cat` and you can use `printf` which might be easier to get the desired output

```
awk -F\| '{printf("ALTER TABLE \"%s\".\"\%s\" WITH gc_grace_seconds=0;\n", $1, $2)}' < table_list
```